# Basics of real numbers in mathcomp (Coq)

Tags: coq, coq-mathcomp

I'm trying to play around with the Mathematical Components library in Coq but am having trouble writing basic, concrete statements about real numbers. E.g., I'd like to define

```
Definition add_two_and_a_half (x : R) : R := x + (2 + 1/2).
```

and then prove

```
Lemma six_and_two_and_a_half_make_eight_and_a_half : add_two_and_a_half 6 = (8 + 1/2)%R.
```

This works fine if I use the Coq.Reals.Reals library, but once I introduce mathcomp the lemma no longer goes through. What are some ways I can make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have opened `ring_scope`, for instance with

```
Local Open Scope ring_scope.
```

you can use 2%:R to mean the constant 2 in a ring instead of nat (or use MathComp >= 1.15.0 where 2 should work).

Comment: Ah, I had been trying to typecast with 2%R instead of 2%:R, this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra ssralg ssrint ssrnum.
From mathcomp.analysis Require Import reals.
From mathcomp.algebra_tactics Require Import ring.

Variable R: realType.

Definition add_two_and_a_half (x : R) : R := x + (2 + 1/2).

Lemma six_and_two_and_a_half_make_eight_and_a_half : add_two_and_a_half 6 = (8 + 1/2)%R.
Proof.
 unfold add_two_and_a_half.
 by ring.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks! The definition of add_two_and_a_half still doesn't go through -- "The term "2" has type "nat"
while it is expected to have type
 "GRing.Zmodule.sort ?V"."

Comment: Ah, perhaps you don't have a recent enough version of mathcomp & rest...

Comment: Could be! I just installed a couple weeks ago so I thought my version was newest... but perhaps not...

Comment: My mathcomp is 1.15.0, mathcomp-analysis 0.5.2 and mathcomp-algebra-tactics is 1.0.0.

Comment: Update: upgraded and this worked! Thank you!